# Excel Conditional Formatting for Two Cells Within Percentage of Each Other

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I was hoping someone could help me with this dilemma. I've been using Conditional Formatting for a while, but I've been having trouble with this option.

I have two cells in an excel worksheet (`I33` and `M33`) that I'm looking to flag red if these two values are within **+-0.25%** of each other. Anyone with advice on the rule that would work?

Comment: Conditional Format Formula: `=ABS($I33-$M33)<=0.0025` Applies to range: `=$I$33:$I$45,$M$33:$M$45`

Answer (score 1):

Clear any existing Conditional Formatting from I33 and M33 and select I33, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=ABS($I33-$M33)/MIN($I33,$M33)<0.0025
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill <kbd>OK</kbd> and adjust the Applies to range to `=$I$33,$M$33`.